# grant remote access to mysql

Tags: mysql, centos6

Hello I am on a Centos VPS with nginx + mysql + php-fpm installed. I am trying to allow remote access to a database on this machine from another of my VPS.

I tried out the following steps.

- Modified the `/etc/my.cnf` file and then within the `[mysqld]` block added the lines `bind-address = *`
- Saved and restarted the mysql service using the command `/etc/init.d/mysqld restart`
- Logged into mysql and created an user by the name **remote** and password say **pass**
- Typed the 'use social' command and tried to run the command `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO remote@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';` Where 1.2.3.4 is the IP of the VPS I want to remote access the **social** database from.

The error is get is

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Can someone let me know why I am encountering this error when I can log in and create users even operate on the database using the same username, root and the same password even after this error!!

Comment: What is the exact command you are issuing to get the above error ?

Comment: Can you start mysql client as root? `mysql -u root -ppasswd`?

Comment: yes i can start mysql client using 'mysql -u root -p`

Comment: the exact command used was  `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO remote@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';` The only difference is the IP and the password I am a bit worried about having to produce the IP and password in an open forum

Comment: @RickRoy: You get that error message when you run the grant command ?

Comment: Yes I get the error when I run the grant command

Comment: Makes me think about a similar problem i had...Have you upgraded your Mysql ? Can you try `mysql_upgrade -u root -p` (take a snapshot before)

Comment: @user2196728 I was able to fix it by modifying the grant command to `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO remote@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';` where dbname is the name of the database that i want to remotely operate upon. But I still dont understand why I am not allowed to run the `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO remote@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this command you are creating an other root user

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO remote@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
```

because you are given all privileges on mysql db too

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON socialdb.* TO remote@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
```